# Supply additional translations for libraries that come via CocoaPods in Flutter App

Tags: ios, flutter, localization

I have a Flutter application that is consuming a plugin that provides some native UI in iOS and Android and naturally brings its own translations for that UI.

Now, the languages I need are not provided and I need to override/add my own translations.

On Android, I can simply add my own resource file and during the build the resource files will be merged properly.

But I cannot get this to work on iOS.

I tried adding the same keys that are used in the pod in my own LocalizedStrings files, but they are not picked up.

I then tried to create a `.strings` file with the same name as is used in the pod, but that also did not work.

I assume this has to do with how the library loads its translations as well.

Is there a way to achieve what I need or do I have to add the translation in the pod itself?